# How to reduce hard coding of dialog flow in MSBot?

Tags: c#, bots, botframework

I am creating a dialog flow in `MSBot` and I am hard-coding the content which will be displayed in `Bot Emulator`.

For example I want to make the dialog flow for creating the steps, and in rich cards there will be a button for the next step.  Now the content I will be creating for the rich card, I have to hard-code in C# if I have a single dialog flow.

But if I have to create the dialog flow for other possible use cases, then I have to hard-code it for everyone.

So is there a way to reduce my effort for hard-coding each of the dialogs? Because if I have to change the steps then I have to manually go to that file and change the whole logic.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do this in a generic fashion, where the source for the dialog flow steps are retrieved from a database or some other store.  Please see this simple example: https://github.com/EricDahlvang/MultiTurnHelpStepsBot

The current step is stored in context.ConversationData(), and when the user clicks next or back, context.ConversationData() is checked to determine what to show next.

Comment: can we store it in JSON file and retrieve the data from it.?

Comment: Yes.  A bot is just a website and messages are sent in json format.

Comment: I mean the dialogs which you have stored in a class ,can we store same dialogs in the JSON format?

Comment: Yes, you can store entire messages in .json format, and load them with: var activityFromJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Activity>(cardJsonText);